# Creating multiple Spring Data JPA Data Source Connections in One Application

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a need to dynamically create and connect to potentially hundreds of databases using from a single ResourceServer (REST Server).  The REST controller would do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/teachers")
public List<Teacher> teachers(@RequestParam(value="db", defaultValue="db") String db) {
    //Look up the correct datasource
    DataSource ds = DSSources.get(db);
    //Associate the datasource with the repository
    ...
    //Return the teachers from the database using 
    //the TeacherRepository (Spring Data JPA Repository)
    return TeacherRepository.getAllTeachers();
}
```

I'm thinking that the `DSSources` is a `Map<String, Datasource` that contains the DataSource instances.  How do I programmatically create the datasources?  Once they are created, how are they associated with the Spring Data JPA Repositories?  All databases will share a common set of repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Storing Datasource in a Map is not a good solution has you have to think of Datasources failing and recreating those as well.

What you need is Multi Tenancy. If you use Hibernate underneath JPA you can use [Hibernate Multi Tenancy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html). I am pretty sure other ORMs also do provide Multi Tenancy capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  Do you know if it integrates with Spring Boot?  I'm using JPA Repository Interfaces for all CRUD operations, so I need to be able to get the tentant connection passed along to Spring somehow ...

Comment: If you're using spring-boot, an alternative will be to use Spring's AbstractRoutingDataSource to manage the routing of each client connection to their respective Datasources.

Comment: Thanks I found a good tutorial on that here [Dynamic Database Routing](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/) but if uses XML to configure the datasource.  I need to be able to add and remove sources on the fly.